# How to use condition statement when we want to check that class exist or not?

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, cypress

In the Cypress I want to create a condition to check if a class was created or not, and make same steps if yes.

I saw a documentation at:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#A-B-campaign

I wrote an example:

```
 cy.get('.footerWrapper').then((div) => {
        if (div.find('.TestClass')) {
            cy.log('xxx')

        } else {
            cy.log('yyy')
        }
    })
```

But the condition is always true, even when I use find() and children() and 'TestClass' class not exist. 'TestClass' is child of 'footerWrapper' class

How should it be written? Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for the `.length` property, because an empty array [] always gives `true` inside of "if" condition.

```
 cy.get('.footerWrapper').then((div) => {
        if (div.find('.TestClass').length) {
            cy.log('xxx')

        } else {
            cy.log('yyy')
        }
    })
```